# Jquery-Visible is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Trying to hide all .intro class divs when the page loads, but when scrolled I want them to fade in. I am using animate.css and jquery-visible. I also tried to use withinViewport.js, viewport.js and bunch of others. I cannot get this to work.

```
<div class="section " id="section0" data-anchor="firstPage">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>Navigation dots</h1>
            <p>An easy and beautiful way to navigate throw the sections</p><p>phone number</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section1" data-anchor="secondPage">
            <div class="intro">
                <h1>Clickable</h1>
                <p>
                    You can even click on the navigation and jump directly to another section.
                </p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the JS and none of it works.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('.section').addClass("hidden");
    if( $('.section').hasClass('active') ) {
        $('.section').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.section').addClass('visible animated fadeIn');
    }

});   

$(window).scroll(function(){

    if( $('.section').hasClass('active'); ) {
        $('.section').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.section').addClass('visible animated fadeIn');
    }
    if( $('#section1').first().visible() ) {
        $('#section1').children().addClass('visible animated fadeIn');
    }

}    );
```

Comment: you want to add animate effect right...?

Comment: you need to use for each statement if you are having multiple elements with the same classes mate.

Comment: Yes animate text on, but only when specific section is within the viewport.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VMjpXZ

Comment: Well I have multiple ".intro" classes. I want them hidden when the page is loaded, but once in the viewport then show that one specific ".intro" class. Not turn all of them to visible.

Comment: Something like this? https://tympanus.net/Blueprints/OnScrollEffectLayout/

Answer (score 1):

Please use animate.css and wow.js and you can add any animate class as you want.

```js
wow = new WOW(
      {
          boxClass: 'wow',      // default
          animateClass: 'animated', // default
          offset: 0,          // default
          mobile: true,       // default
          live: true        // default
      }
    )
wow.init();
```

```css
body{
  overflow-x:hidden; /*for animation purpose*/
}
.intro{
  height:500px;/*this is only for example*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>


<div class="section wow fadeInDown" id="section0" data-anchor="firstPage">
  <div class="intro">
      <h1>Navigation dots</h1>
      <p>An easy and beautiful way to navigate throw the sections</p><p>phone number</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="section wow fadeInLeft" id="section1" data-anchor="secondPage">
  <div class="intro">
    <h1>Clickable</h1>
    <p>
        You can even click on the navigation and jump directly to another section.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="section wow fadeInRight" id="section2" data-anchor="thirdPage">
  <div class="intro">
    <h1>Clickable</h1>
    <p>
        You can even click on the navigation and jump directly to another section.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="section wow fadeInLeft" id="section3" data-anchor="forthPage">
  <div class="intro">
    <h1>Clickable</h1>
    <p>
        You can even click on the navigation and jump directly to another section.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```